# Use instanceof in Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-el

Is there a way to use the Java `instanceof` operator in Thymeleaf?

Something like:

```html
<span th:if="${animal} instanceof my.project.Cat" th:text="A cat"></span>
<span th:if="${animal} instanceof my.project.Dog" th:text="A dog"></span>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try:

`<span th:if="${animal.class.name == 'my.project.Cat'}" th:text="A cat"></span>`

or, if using Spring:

`<span th:if="${animal instanceof T(my.project.Cat)}" th:text="A cat"></span>`

more about [using SpEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/expressions.html) and [dialects in thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#dialects-the-standard-dialect).