# How to check classtype of a table field in thymeleaf?

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a generic `thymeleaf` table as follows:

```
 <tbody>
        <th:block th:each="row : ${page.getContent()}">
            <tr>
                 <td th:each="header : ${headers}" th:text="${row.__${header}__}"/>
            </tr>
        </th:block>
    </tbody>
```

The table is simply backed by a list containing my domain objects:

```
List<Header> headers = List.of("firstname", "lastname");
List<Person> page;
```

What it does is: it loops my predefined list `headers`, and selects only those attributes defined in the headers list.

Question: how could I add an evaluation on the **classtype** of the extracted value of each field, so that I could apply a custom style in case of digits?

The problem is: when I output the class of the value that is shown, the output is a `java.util.ArrayList` *always*!

```
th:text="${{row.__${header}__}.class.name}"
```

Why doesn't this show the correct class of the `td` element?

Comment: `X.getClass() instanceof Y` is never useful. `X.getClass()` always returns an instance of `Class` and nothing else. It's either `X instanceof Y` or `x.getClass().equals(Y)`

Comment: have you tried `head.class.name instanceof T(java.math.BigDecimal)`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use instanceof in Thymeleaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783272/use-instanceof-in-thymeleaf)

Comment: @bphilipnyc see my update. I tried all the suggestions, but still cannot access the class type.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to evaluate the header if you go down a level.  My thought is that the preprocessor operation may not give you a reference to the `header` object on the same `td` element.

This use case may also be a good candidate for `th:classappend` since you may want to inherit some style.

Also, not sure whether it applies, but table headings are typically wrapped in a `<thead>` element.  Then, I would assume you'd want a list of `Person` objects iterated in a `<tbody>`.

Haven't tested it, but try:

```
<thead>
     <th:block th:each="header : ${headers}">
          <th th:text="${header}" class="someClass" th:classappend="${header.name.class instanceof T(java.math.BigDecimal) ? 'someDigitClassStyle' : ''}" />
      </th:block> 
<thead>
```

Assumes use of Spring.  [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783272/use-instanceof-in-thymeleaf)

Lastly, you can consider an [Apache util](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35072931/check-if-a-string-contains-number-or-is-numeric-thymeleaf) for `isNumeric` if you want to more broadly catch digits.

Answer (score 0):

Solution as follows to apply a specific css style based on instance check:

```
 th:text="${row.__${header}__}"
 th:style="${{row.__${header}__}.get(0) instanceof T(java.math.BigDecimal)} ? 'text-align:right' : ''"/>
```